# Produce heading hierarchy as ordered list

Tags: javascript, html, methodology

I've been pondering this for a while but cannot come up with a working solution. I can't even psuedo code it...

Say, for example, you have a page with a heading structure like this:

```
<h1>Heading level 1</h1>

    <h2>Sub heading #1</h2>

    <h2>Sub heading #2</h2>

        <h3>Sub Sub heading</h3>

    <h2>Sub heading #3</h2>

        <h3>Sub Sub heading #1</h3>

        <h3>Sub Sub heading #2</h3>

            <h4>Sub Sub Sub heading</h4>

    <h2>Sub heading #4</h2>

        <h3>Sub Sub heading</h3>
```

Using JavaScript (any framework is fine), how would you go about producing a list like this: (with nested lists)

```
<ol>
    <li>Heading level 1
        <ol>
            <li>Sub heading #1</li>
            <li>Sub heading #2
                <ol>
                    <li>Sub Sub heading</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Sub heading #3
                <ol>
                    <li>Sub Sub heading #1</li>
                    <li>Sub Sub heading #2
                        <ol>
                            <li>Sub Sub Sub heading (h4)</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Sub heading #4
                <ol>
                    <li>Sub Sub heading</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Everytime I try and begin with a certain methodology it ends up getting very bloated.

The solution needs to traverse each heading and put it into its appropriate nested list - I keep repeating this to myself but I can't sketch out anything!

Even if you have a methodology in your head but haven't got time to code it up I'd still like to know it! :)

Thank you!

Comment: @JimmyP: is there content between headings?  Does that content need to live in the final structure?

Comment: Old topic, but in the current implementation of jQuery (1.10.2), `$('h1, ... , h6')` will return the tags in the order that they appear on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, build a tree.  Pseudocode (because I'm not fluent in Javascript):

```
var headings = array(...);
var treeLevels = array();
var treeRoots = array();

foreach(headings as heading) {
    if(heading.level == treeLevels.length) {
        /* Adjacent siblings. */

        if(heading.level == 1) {
            treeRoots[] = heading;  // Append.
        } else {
            treeLevels[treeLevels.length - 2].children[] = heading;  // Add child to parent element.
        }

        treeLevels[treeLevels.length - 1] = heading;
    } else if(heading.level > treeLevels.length) {
        /* Child. */

        while(heading.level - 1 > treeLevels.length) {
            /* Create dummy headings if needed. */
            treeLevels[] = new Heading();
        }

        treeLevels[] = heading;
    } else {
        /* Child of ancestor. */

        treeLevels.remove(heading.level, treeLevels.length - 1);

        treeLevels[treeLevels.length - 1].children[] = heading;
        treeLevels[] = heading;
    }
}
```

Next, we transverse it, building the list.

```
function buildList(root) {
    var li = new LI(root.text);

    if(root.children.length) {
        var subUl = new UL();
        li.children[] = subUl;

        foreach(root.children as child) {
            subUl.children[] = buildList(child);
        }
    }

    return li; 
}
```

Finally, insert the `LI` returned by `buildList` into a `UL` for each `treeRoots`.

In jQuery, you can fetch header elements in order as such:

```
var headers = $('*').filter(function() {
    return this.tagName.match(/h\d/i);
}).get();
```

Comment: The problem here is that there is not any good way to retrieve the headings in document order.  For example the jQuery call $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6') will return all of your headings, but all <h1>s will come first followed by the <h2>s, and so on.  No major frame work yet returns document order.

Comment: @Prestaul, I have added a jQuery snippet to show how you would do this.  Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @strager, that is a nice work around.  I just posted a solution that (with jQuery) gets the list by first adding a common class to the headings: $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').addClass('heading'); var $aiches = $('.heading');

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that there is not any good way to retrieve the headings in document order. For example the jQuery call `$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')` will return all of your headings, but all `<h1>`s will come first followed by the `<h2>`s, and so on. No major frame work yet returns elements in document order when you use comma delimited selectors.

You could overcome this issue by adding a common class to each heading.  For example:

```
<h1 class="heading">Heading level 1</h1>

    <h2 class="heading">Sub heading #1</h2>

    <h2 class="heading">Sub heading #2</h2>

        <h3 class="heading">Sub Sub heading</h3>

    <h2 class="heading">Sub heading #3</h2>

    ...
```

Now the selector `$('.heading')` will get them all in order.

Here is how I would do it with jQuery:

```
var $result = $('<div/>');
var curDepth = 0;

$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').addClass('heading');
$('.heading').each(function() {

    var $li = $('<li/>').text($(this).text());

    var depth = parseInt(this.tagName.substring(1));

    if(depth > curDepth) { // going deeper

        $result.append($('<ol/>').append($li));
        $result = $li;

    } else if (depth < curDepth) { // going shallower

        $result.parents('ol:eq(' + (curDepth - depth - 1) + ')').append($li);
        $result = $li;

    } else { // same level

        $result.parent().append($li);
        $result = $li;

    }

    curDepth = depth;

});

$result = $result.parents('ol:last');

// clean up
$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').removeClass('heading');
```

`$result` should now be your `<ol>`.

Also, note that this will handle an `<h4>` followed by an `<h1>` (moving more than one level down at once), but it will not handle an `<h1>` followed by an `<h4>` (more than one level up at a time).

Comment: caution: `$result.parents('li:eq ...` should be `$result.parents('ol:eq ...`, since we are appending to the ordered list and not the list item.

Comment: This is a great, and very complete solution. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be only `'ol:eq(' + (curDepth - depth) + ')'`?

Answer (score 2):

I can envision many situations where you might be overthinking this. For many situations, you would really only need the *appearance* of the hierarchy, and not the actual regenerated HTML hierarchy itself, for which you can do something simple like this:

```
#nav li.h1 { padding: 0 0 0  0px; } #nav li.h1:before { content: 'h1 '; }
#nav li.h2 { padding: 0 0 0 10px; } #nav li.h2:before { content: 'h2 '; }
#nav li.h3 { padding: 0 0 0 20px; } #nav li.h3:before { content: 'h3 '; }
#nav li.h4 { padding: 0 0 0 30px; } #nav li.h4:before { content: 'h4 '; }
#nav li.h5 { padding: 0 0 0 40px; } #nav li.h5:before { content: 'h5 '; }
#nav li.h6 { padding: 0 0 0 50px; } #nav li.h6:before { content: 'h6 '; }
```

```
for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h'+i);
    for (j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
        headers[j].className = 'h';
    }
}
var headers = document.getElementsByClassName('h');
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
h1.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('ul'),h1.nextSibling);
h1.nextSibling.id = 'nav';
for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('nav').innerHTML += '<li class="'+headers[i].tagName.toLowerCase()+'">'+headers[i].innerHTML+'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will select all h1-h6 tags into the docElTgt DOM section of the document and will be respected the order heading are into the html document

```
var hItemsList = docElTgt.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
```

examples of the value that can be docElTgt:

```
docElTgt = document.body;
docElTgt = anyelement.id;
```

After selected all heading it will be possible to apply algorithm to make hierarchy as ordered list as showed by others users